# how to ask windows 7 to connect to 3G each time it's waking up?

Tags: windows-7, connection, scheduled-tasks, task-manager

I have a USB 3G modem which is used with Windows 7. It's connected to my notebook almost always.
When i tell computer to sleep, the connection to 3G network closes. I want the connection to start after waking the computer up.
What do I set up for it? There is a trigger "when i log on" in Task Sheduler, but I can't find "when the computer wakes up"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 3g device supports Windows 7 mobile broadband , you can just select the connect automatically or connect automatically when not roaming option. It will reconnect automatically and presents the connection like a wifi connection.